# Altering list while iterating

Tags: python

Python noob here. I have a list of numbers represented as strings. Single digit numbers are represented with a zero and I'm trying to get rid of the zeroes. For instance, ['01', '21', '03'] should be ['1', '21', '3'].

My current solution seems a bit clumsy:

```
for item in list:  
    if item[0] == '0':     
        list[list.index(item)] = item[1]
```

I'm wondering why this doesn't work:

```
for item in list:  
    if item[0] == '0':  
        item = item[1]
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as the name of a variable, because it shadows the built-in name `list`. Incidentally, the `list[list.index(item)] = ...` won't work when the list contains duplicates. Use `for idx, item in enumerate(list): \n list[idx] = ...` if you ever need a counter; but in this case there are better approaches anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Rebinding the iterating name does not mutate the list.

Also:

```
>>> [str(int(x, 10)) for x in ['01', '21', '03']]
['1', '21', '3']
```

Comment: I prefer the `lstrip` approach here.

Answer (score 3):

You could try stripping the zero:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x.lstrip('0'), ['001', '002', '030'])
['1', '2', '30']
```

Answer (score 3):

To mutate the list:

```
for i, item in enumerate(mylist):  
    if item.startswith('0'):     
        mylist[i] = item[1:]
```

Better is probably just to create a new list:

```
new_list = [x.lstrip('0') for x in mylist]
```

Your code doesn't work because assigning to `item` merely gives the name `item` a new value, it doesn't do anything to the old value of `item`.

Answer (score -1):

The code "item" is a variable that contains the *value* of the item as you iterate through the list.  It has no reference to the list itself.

Your first solution is very slow because it will have to search the list for each item to find the index.

See other answers for examples of how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Why is this downvoted??  Read http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down if you don't understand the concept of voting here.